# How to specify the directory for .snakemake/log?

Tags: snakemake

When executing Snakemake, it creates log file (e.g. **.snakemake/log/2023-12-13T155741.107386.snakemake.log** ) in the directory where I execute the command. It immediately crashes, if I don't have write permission to this directory.

How can I specify a directory for this log file? The version of Snakemake that I am using is 5.18.1.

I have checked its Help menu and couldn't find the option/parameter for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--directory/-d` option to set the working directory. Snakemake will change to that directory before starting processing. The `.snakemake` directory will be written there as well.

Unrelated, snakemake 5.18.1 is quite old now and I would upgrade unless you have a valid reason not to.

Comment: Using the `--directory/-d` option overwrites the `workdir` that I define in my snakefile file. As a results, my workflow fails as it needs the `workdir` to locate my input and output.

Comment: `-d` doesn't overwrite. Maybe open a new question explaining this problem with an example. Chances are that there is either a simple solution or a better setup of your workflow.